# How to add leading spaces in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add leading spaces in one of the column of the table. This ID column has data type Char(6).

Example: Table1

```
ID
1234
5678
```

when I do select * from Table1. and save file into .csv with pipeline delimited.
It show spaces at the end of number.

Current output:

```
 |1234  |
 |5678  |
```

desired output

```
 |  1234|
 |  5678|
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle?  Or MySQL?  The definition of `char(6)` requires the data to be exactly 6 bytes long (as opposed to a variable width `varchar(6)`) right-padded with spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select LPAD(trim(id), 2) from table
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to `trim` the value to remove the trailing spaces and then `lpad` it to add the leading spaces

```
select lpad(trim(id),6)
  from your_table
```

Here is a [sqlfiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09874/3) that shows the steps