# UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA trimming the extra spaces in the email body | Oracle

Tags: oracle

**Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.20.0.0.0**

I am using the UTL_SMTP to send an email. Below is code

```
declare
 l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
  l_boundary    VARCHAR2(50) := '              =abc1234321cba=';
  p_smtp_host VARCHAR2 (100) := 'smtp.cac.com';
   p_smtp_port      NUMBER := 25;
   p_to VARCHAR2(100) := 'hello@gmail.com';
   p_subject VARCHAR2(100) := 'Hello';
   p_html_msg  VARCHAR2(100) :=  '              ' ||'ABC <br>' || '              ' || 'DEF';
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_to);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);

  UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);
  
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' || l_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

  IF p_html_msg IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, p_html_msg);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
/
```

I am able to receive the email but the email body is trimming the repeated spaces whether they are leading or trailing

**Output with above code is**

[image]

**Expected output is**

[image]

Please observe the leading spaces are highlighted in the expected output. I am unable to understand what went wrong with this code.

Thanks for reading, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please not above code is taken from google and trying to work on it

Comment: have you tried lpad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638626/how-to-add-leading-spaces-in-oracle

Comment: @nbk, lpad is same as additional spaces into the string, here is the problem is with write_data in HTML format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not about Oracle it is about html. Try to set

```
   p_html_msg  VARCHAR2(100) :=  '<pre>' || '              ' ||'ABC <br>' || '              ' || 'DEF';
```

or

```
p_html_msg  VARCHAR2(100) :=  '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp' ||'ABC <br>' || '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp' || 'DEF';
```

https://blog.hubspot.com/website/html-space

Comment: Used the first solution, perfectly worked. Thanks a ton for quick response.

Comment: With the same Oracle procedure, I am sending a hyperlink(like Click here). When I focus on word *here*, the web page link is appearing, is there a way to hide the display of the link?

Comment: I am not sure if understand your question. Try attribut title:
<a href="/" title="Click here">Click here</a>

Comment: Okay, thats fine to have the link displayed when the mouse is moved. But one more thing, I am using the hyperlink for a file placed on internal shared folder and the file has a single quote as part of its name, when I click on the link, it is not opening as the file name is converted to "Venkat's file.txt'" from its original name "Venkat's file.txt". Any suggestion? Please observe an extra single quote at the end of converted file name. That was added automatically while opening the link

Comment: So You have something like this <a href="Venkat's file.txt">Click here</a> ?

Comment: Apologies, I missed your message, Yes the file includes the tag. And also, after receiving the email when I move the cursor on the hyperlink name, the file path is being displayed which I want to hide. Hope you understand this.

Comment: I am sorry, I cant help You. Try to create new question with some samples of Your code.